# Error while running VBS script

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am trying to run excel macro using VBS and getting attached error. Is there a way to enable macro at the run time? if so, how?

[image]

Comment: Right click file - Properties - Unblock.

Answer (score 2):

This should be done in Excel itself:

- Click the File tab and then click Options.
- Click the Trust Center tab and then click the Trust Center Settings button.
- Click "Enable all macros"
  **Note - it is not recommended for a reason to do so!**
- Set the checkbox to "Trust access to the VBA project object model"

[image]

Comment: I stand corrected, `DisplayAlerts` set to `False` my not be able to *kill* the pop-up. Although it worked for me even on network files. I however checked my *Trusted Document* and *Trusted Location* list and most (not all) of the files I execute macro from are there. But then again, I have distributed `VBS` file to many different users and it works just by using the `DisplayAlerts = False`. Anyhow, if the OP confirms it does not help, I'll delete it for now. Cheers! :)

Comment: @L42 - yup, the checkbox is important.